# how to get one class from multiple classes in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let check1 = document.querySelectorAll('.container input');
        check1.forEach((elem)=>{
            elem.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes');
                boxes.forEach((ele)=>{
                    let boxesId = ele.getAttribute("class");
                    console.log(boxesId) //now there are three classes shown (boxes karat size)how to get size class
                })               
            })
        })
```

i am trying to get one class from multiple classes in javascript

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do with this specific class name? If it’s just to test for the existence of a specific class you can use `ele.classList.contains()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using
`ele.getAttribute("class");`

Use the classList property.

`let boxesId = ele.classList[2];`

classList will return a list of all the classes. See [documantation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

Comment: thank u let boxesId = ele.classList[2]; this method works for me..

Answer (score -2):

Why you wanna do this? Sorry i can't understand.
But if you wann check if a element have a clas you can use the method includes.

```
element.classList.contains(className)
```